# Shell - Variable scope and assignment

Tags: shell, variables, unix, scope, variable-assignment

I am curious as to why the assignment to the variable "nameExists" is not working as desired in the following code:

```
        nameExists=1
        cat $dataFile | while read line
        do
            lineName=${line%%:*}
            if [ "$lineName" == "$name" ]
            then
                echo "The entry you are trying to add already exists!"
                nameExists=0
                break
            fi
        done

        if [ $nameExists -eq 1 ]
        then
            echo "Append here."
        fi
```

I have found that, regardless of whether I reach the inner assignment "nameExists=0", the value of $nameExists is always 1.  I am wondering if this is because the nameExists variable inside the do loop is being considered a local variable.  If so how would I declare the nameExists variable or assign to the nameExists variable in such a way that the value of 0 remains after assigned.

Comment: did you turn on shell debugging/trace feature? `set -vx` will show you  next blocks and statments to be executed, then each line as it executes with a `+` sign at the front and values substituted for variables. Occasional shellisms like changing most strings to single-quoted strings and using of other standardizing notations can confuse the issue, so focus on the values of variables and assume the `-vx` option is doing the right thing with your strings. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my issue was relative simple and gleaned from the article here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

By introducing a new SubShell through the pipeline command,

```
cat $dataFile |
```

I subsequently introduced a new variable context and environment specific to the Subshell.  Thus, my assignment "nameExists=0" was scoped locally inside the loop and did not persist once the Subshell finished execution.  I resolved the issue by removing the unnecessary pipeline.  My resulting code works as intended and is shown below.

```
    nameExists=1
    while read -r line
    do
          lineName=${line%%:*}
          if [ "$lineName" == "$name" ]
          then
              echo "The entry you are trying to add already exists!"
              nameExists=0
              break
          fi
    done < $dataFile

    if [ $nameExists -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo "Append here."
    fi
```